# Is there any way to add CanDeactivate type route guard on Spartacus PDP page

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I have to stop navigation on PDP if a certain form is not filled. I wanted to achieve it using a guard. (feel free to suggest an alternative).

The problem here is PDP routes are not defined on sourcecode. and I don't know how to configure it. If I go by the traditional way I need to give a component and that will be an issue Since I am rendering multiple components on that page.

Comment: You can add guard to one of the cms components in the PDP page, interface `CmsComponentMapping<T = CmsComponent>` has `guards` property.

Comment: @Indrajeet Gajbhiye were you able to find a solution for this. I am also trying to achieve something similar.